# Python: writing data to multiple columns in CSV using "with open"

Tags: python, csv

I don't want to use an extra library like pandas to write data from 2 lists into a CSV file.

I tried the below code but get:
**AttributeError: '_io.TextIOWrapper' object has no attribute 'writerows'**

```
list1= ['1970', '1980', '1990']  
list2= [0.9, 1.5, 30]  

with open('output.csv', 'w+') as f:
    
    # for  i in date_list: # For 1 column
    #     f.write("%s\n" %i)
        
    for  i, j in zip(list1, list2): 
        f.writerows(["%s\n" %i, "%s\n" %j])
```

Comment: take a look at the python csv module. `writerows` is a method provided by csvwriter.

Comment: @jdigital: I don't want to import an extra library.

Comment: Try writelines instead writerows.

Comment: @Gregory Oliveira: writelines just write the 2 lists on different rows of the SAME column. I want the 2 lists on DIFFERENT columns

Comment: try  f.write(str(i)+','+str(j)+'\n') instead of writerows